# Is the hyperbolic fixed point of a flow included in the domain of its stable / unstable / homoclinic manifold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, stability-in-odes

Consider a $C^{k}$ map / flow on a plane, with a hyperbolic fixed point at the origin $0$, with a $1$-dimensional stable subspace, and a $1$-dimensional unstable subspace. By the stable /unstable manifold theorem, there exist $1$-dim stable and unstable manifolds $W^{s,u}(0)$ of $0$. Further, suppose that these manifolds coincide in a figure-8 homoclinic loop $\Gamma \subset W^{s}(0) \cap W^{u}(0)$.

Many authors refer to the homoclinic loop as "homoclinic manifold".

My question is, in what sense is this a manifold - since strictly speaking, figure 8 is not a topological / differentiable manifold (due to the point of self-intersection)?

The only way this can be if the origin is removed from the domain of definition of $\Gamma$...So does this mean that the domain of definition of $W^{s,u}(0)$ also excludes $0$?

Or in the context of smooth dynamical systems, the terms stable / unstable / homoclinic manifolds also refer to manifolds with certain "singularities"?

Comment: I would appreciate if you could indicate a single mathematician referring to it as "homoclinic manifold", certainly people outside mathematics since this is incorrect (as you detail quite well). We always want the point there and we worry instead of having or not homoclinic orbits (orbits approaching the point in the future and in the past).

Comment: There are quite many papers, both very recent and old, that refer to "homoclinic manifolds". See for instance the paper by Wiggins and Haller, "N-Pulse Homoclinic Orbits in Perturbations
of Resonant Hamiltonian Systems". @JohnB

Comment: Hence my question. Note that I am also referring to a general case, where the homoclinic is not just a single orbit, but rather a higher dimensional invariant set containing orbits that asymptotically tend towards another invariant set in the future and past (for example like in the paper I referred to above). So suppose $\Lambda$ is some invariant manifold that has stable/unstable manifolds $W^{s,u}(\Lambda)$; suppose $W^{s,u}$ coincide in a homoclinic loop $\Gamma$... Do we specifically exclude $\Lambda$ from domain of $\Gamma$ or not? Or is "homoclinic manifold" just an abuse of notation?

Comment: As I said, "homoclinic orbits" (see the title of the paper). :) Really they should not use that expression, if you can indicate someone in the area one can proceed from there. Anyways, we always include the reference orbit (or orbits, as with $\Lambda$) and indeed you are right, it is always an "abuse" of expression.

Comment: In that paper, they specifically refer to a $2$ dimensional smooth "homoclinic manifold".  I can also point out a recent paper by Delshams  et all "Arnold diffusion for a complete family of perturbations" that uses this term @JohnB

Comment: I wrote "in the area", one cannot take as examples people who is clearly perceived as outsiders.